# JQuery on click requires two clicks on element loaded with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, onclick

I have a menu that is put on the page using PHP. When I click on the menu-open icon, it opens with only one click. When I attempt to close the menu however, it requires two clicks to close. I've posted the relevant code below. There are a few related questions on Stack Overflow, but none of them seem to address the issue I'm having. I'm quite new at this, so I apologize in advance for any ignorance on my part.

HTML (Main page):

```
<section class="menu">
<?php include 'menu.htm';?>
</section>
```

Here is the menu.htm code:

```
<?php 
echo '<i class="menu-button fa fa-bars"></i>
    <div class="menu-grid hidden">
      <i class="nav-jpn fas fa-globe-asia"></i>
      <i class="nav-eng fas fa-globe-americas"></i>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Projects</a>
        <a href="">Recipes</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <i class="nav-close fas fa-times"></i>
    </div>';
?>
```

And here is the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(() =>{
  // Menu
  $('.menu-button').on('click', () =>{
    $('.menu-grid').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
  $('.nav-close').on('click', () =>{
    $('.menu-grid').toggleClass('hidden')
  });
  $('.menu-grid').on('mouseout',() =>{
    $('.menu-grid').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

Here's the CSS as well:

```
/* Drop-down nav menu */
  .menu-button{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: black;
  }
  .menu-grid{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5px auto auto repeat(12, [menu-col-start] 1fr) auto 5px;
    grid-template-rows: 5px auto auto 5px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: goldenrod;
  }
  .nav-jpn{
    grid-column:2/span 1;
    grid-row: 2;
    font-size: 2rem;
    justify-self: stretch;
  }
  .nav-eng{
    grid-column: 3 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2;
    font-size: 2rem;

  }
  .nav-close{
    grid-column: -3/ span 1;
    grid-row: 2;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .nav-links{
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 3;
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;

  }
    .nav-links a{
      font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
      color: goldenrod;
      background-color: black;
      font-size: 3rem;
      margin: auto;
    }

  /* Media Queries */
  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    .nav-links{
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .nav-links a{
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      margin: 0 .5rem;
    }
    .nav-links {
      grid-column: 4 / 16;
      grid-row: 2;
    }
    .menu-grid{
      grid-template-rows: 5px auto 5px;
    }
  }
```

It would be great if anyone could shed any light on the issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: perhaps you can include the **css** as well so we can reproduce the issue. because currently, just by looking at this, I think it should work fine

Comment: CSS added above. That's part of why I'm so confused; it seems like it should be working totally fine. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: Logically for me no need to `.toggleClass` on `.nav-close` click and `.menu-grid` mouseout .. you can try `.addClass` instead

Comment: @Ben do you use the `<i class="nav-close fas fa-times"></i>` element in order to close the menu? if so, I think I know what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is happening when you are clicking on 'nav-close'.
And the reason may be that as you click on 'nav-close' toggleClass function is called and as 'menu-grid' is hidden it calls the 'mouseout' event making it visible again.

Comment: This seems to be correct! If I either remove the mouseout event or change toggleClass to addClass the close button works! Thank you all so much!